# Diffeomorfism invariance

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a diffeomorphism $f:M \rightarrow M$ with a  one form $\omega$
and a vector field $X$ .

And suppose this diffeomorphism leaves  $\omega$ and $X$ unchanged.
How can we proof that $\omega(X)_{p}=\omega(X)_{f^{-1}(p)}$ ?

Here $\omega(X)_{p}$ is evaluated before the application of $f$ and  $\omega(X)_{f^{-1}(p)}$ after $

Comment: Can you write down in formula the definition of "keeping $\omega$ and X unchanged"?

Comment: we think that $\omega$ and $X$ are actors in stage and that for a second they both jump, while the stage is shifted.